# Удаление вершины с графа

Tags: c++, графы

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
using namespace std;


class Graph
{
    int V;    

    list<int> *adj;


    void DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[]);

public:
    Graph(int V);   

    void addEdge(int v, int w); 

    void DFS(int v); 

    void print();

    void deleteVertex(int v);
};

Graph::Graph(int V)
{
    this->V = V;
    adj = new list<int>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w)
{
    adj[v].push_back(w); 
    adj[w].push_back(v);
}


void Graph::print() {
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++) {
        cout << "List: " << v << endl;
        for (auto x : adj[v])
            cout << "-->" << x;
        cout << endl;
    }
}

void Graph::deleteVertex(int v)
{
    //adj[v].remove();
}


void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[])
{
    visited[v] = true;
    cout << v << " ";
    list<int>::iterator i; 
    for (i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
        if (!visited[*i])
            DFSUtil(*i, visited);
}


void Graph::DFS(int v)
{

    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
        visited[i] = false;

    DFSUtil(v, visited);
}

int main()
{
    int size;
    cout << "Enter count of Vertex" << endl;
    cin >> size;

    Graph g(size);

    int firstVertex, secondVertex;
    int answer = 1, i = 0;

    while (answer != 0 && i < size - 1) {
        i++;

        cout << "Enter conected Vertex: \n";
        cin >> firstVertex;
        cin >> secondVertex;
        cout << "Do you want to continue? 1 yes 0 - no" << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        cout << "\nCurrent i is" << i << endl;

        g.addEdge(firstVertex, secondVertex);
    }

    g.deleteVertex(2);

    g.DFS(0);
    cout << endl;
    g.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Как реализовать правильно функцию удаления вершины?
Если возможно помогите кодом

Comment: А нужно чтобы связи сохранились,допустим был граф 1-2-3 Удалим вершину 2 и станет 1-3 или нужно 1 3?

Comment: Нет,не нужно 1 3 @TEA

Answer (score 0):

1.Вызываем функцию удаления вершины

2.В функции ищем нашу вершину,которую хотим удалить

3.Запоминаем смежные ей вершины(их же максимум 2?)

4.Делаем одно общее ребро для смежных вершин

5.Удаляем вершину из графа (...delete()...)